# Bootstrap tabs - custom style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve the same kind of 'arrow' styling on bootstrap tabs similar to the screenshot below. How can I achieve something similar?

I have my sample code in jsfiddle where I used bootstrap tabs.
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/70Luf7hu/

```
<div>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>     </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#office" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Office</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#confirmation" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Confirm</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">Home</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="office">Office</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="confirmation">Confirm</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It appears you only put the BS code and didn't do any styling of your own. Also, your fiddle doesn't include the BS js.

Comment: As a starting point, check out [Achieving arrow-like shapes in a banner in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077051/achieving-arrow-like-shapes-in-a-banner-in-css) or [How to make this arrow in CSS only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636373/how-to-make-this-arrow-in-css-only)

Answer (score 5):

by using breadcrumb class you can achieve

```css
.breadcrumb {
        background: #ddd;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 1px;
        padding-right: 18px;

    }

    .breadcrumb li {
        display: inline-block;
        background: white;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        min-width:50px;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        margin-right: -13px;
    }

    .breadcrumb li#last {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
    }

    .breadcrumb li:hover {
        color: white;
        background: #fff;
    }

    /* first link should not have anything cliped on the left side */
    .breadcrumb li:first-child {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
    }

    .label{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
 .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
 border:0;
 background-color:#fff;
 }
 .nav-tabs > li > a{padding:10px 30px}
  .nav-tabs > li.active {
  border-bottom:3px solid cyan;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="breadcrumb">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>     </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#office" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Office</a>
    </li>
    <li id="last" role="presentation">
        <a href="#confirmation" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Confirm</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">Home</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="office">Office</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="confirmation">Confirm</div>
    
  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
.nav-tabs > li > a {margin: 0;}
.breadcrumb input[type="radio"] {
display: none;
}
.breadcrumb input[type="checkbox"] {
display: none;
}
.breadcrumb {
background: #ddd;
display: inline-block;
padding: 1px;
padding-right: 14px;
}
.tab-content {
padding: 15px;
}
.breadcrumb li {
display: inline-block;
background: white;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
min-width:50px;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
margin-right: -13px;
}
.breadcrumb li#last {
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover { border-bottom: 2px solid #5cfeea;}
.breadcrumb li:first-child {
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);   
clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
   <!-- Nav tabs -->
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation">
         <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>     
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" class="active">
         <a href="#office" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Office</a>
      </li>
      <li id="last" role="presentation">
         <a href="#confirmation" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Confirm</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <!-- Tab panes -->
   <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">Home</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="office">Office</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="confirmation">Confirm</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Refer this

https://jsfiddle.net/70Luf7hu/10/

Answer (score 2):

well i have modified the above solutions to suit my situation well, i just did a little bit of twerkingto make this work in Bootstrap 4+ . in the code below  i have not included the external CSS or js files for the  Bootstrap 4 framework just copy and paste.

```
<style>
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
        border:0;
        background-color:#0000FF;
    }
    .nav-tabs > li > a{padding:10px 30px}
    .nav-tabs > li.active {
        border-bottom:3px solid blue;
    }


    .c_breadcrumb {
        padding: 1px;
        background: #ddd;
        padding-right: 15px;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        /*
        display: inline-block;

        */
    }

    .c_breadcrumb li {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width:50px;
        background: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        margin-right: -13px;
    }

    .c_breadcrumb li#last {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
    }

    .c_breadcrumb li:hover {
        color: white;
        background: #fff;
    }

    /* first link should not have anything cliped on the left side */
    .c_breadcrumb li:first-child {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
    }


</style>
```

I have used the **nav-fill** class to make my tabs fill space .

```
<div>
    <div  class="c_breadcrumb" >
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs nav-fill" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item " >
                <a class="nav-link active "  data-toggle="tab" href="#submitted">Active</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"  data-toggle="tab" href="#pendingApproval">Longer nav link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"  data-toggle="tab" href="#workInProgress">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled"  data-toggle="tab" href="#complete">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content" style="margin:5%;">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="submitted">
            Submitted data will be displayed here....
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="pendingApproval">
            Pending Approvals will be displayed here....
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="workInProgress">
            In Progress data will be displayed here....
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="complete">
            Completed data will be displayed here....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, remember I have combined the above solutions to suit my scenario, so make changes to suit yours to .
so this should work [image]